# directly launch "add mail account" on MLCFG32.CPL

Tags: windows, outlook

I would like to directly launch "add mail account" on "MLCFG32.CPL" which resides inside here "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16" or here "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16"

is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's available.

Based on my test on this:

1.Locate to: ***C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16*** (different from the path you provided)

2.find MLCFG32.CPL.

3.Double click MLCFG32.CPL and the following window pop out.
[image]

4.Click E-mail Accounts… to add an account.

With all due respect, this is the same as adding in the **Control Panel > Mail** portal.

Hope the above help!

Comment: the question was asking about opening "add a new account" directly not opening the ".CPL" itself.

Comment: However, by opening "MLCFG32.CPL", you can see the entry to add an account. I don't quite understand what you mean. Do you want to have an option to add an account under this path without opening "MLCFG32.CPL"? If so, i'm afraid it's impossible.

Comment: that would be the best, but dorectly opening the "add account"#Dialog would be enough already.

Comment: If so, I'm afraid opening MLCFG32.CPL is the closest way to your requirement.